# Saving game timer?

Tags: unity, savegame

When I load my script, `time` starts from zero. How do I save my game timer?

Here is my script:

```
public float seconds, minutes, hours;
public Text levelTimer;
public float GameTime;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    hours = (int)(GameTime / 3600.0f);
    minutes = (int)(GameTime / 60f);
    seconds = (int)(GameTime % 60f);

    levelTimer.text = hours.ToString("00") + ":" +
            minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + seconds.ToString("00");
    GameTime += Time.deltaTime;
}

public void save()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("second1",seconds);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("mins1",minutes);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("hour1",hours);
}

public void load()
{
    seconds = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("second1");
    minutes = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("mins1");
    hours = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("hour1");
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `load` and `save` at any point?

Comment: I press on save button to save my time example 01:30:40. When i press on load button it not load my save time.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of grammatical coherence and the general absence of even the most elementary-level sentence structure. The question also shows no effort, nor provides enough information for an answer to be generated.

Comment: @Krythic, you should remember that not all users come from English speaking backgrounds, and that many languages use a completely different structure to English. Applying that to this question, it makes perfect sense, to me. It was also answered well before your comments that it does not provide enough information for an answer.

Comment: @Gnemlock This is an English speaking site. Your comment is invalidated.

Comment: @Gnemlock The question has also been heavily edited since my comment was written.

Comment: @Krythic, you are free to check edits by clicking on the "edited.. x hours ago" link. You will note that the only edits made to this post were made after I also commented. By me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Update` method, `hours` `minutes` and `seconds` are always getting updated with `GameTime`, so it won't get the saved preferences. On `load`, you should set your `GameTime` to `seconds + minutes + hours` or just save `GameTime` and use that.

Maybe it's worth that you check [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It may help you with this timer and the way of represent it in a string.